# Sun Ultrasparc 1 creator monitor

Tags: workstation

What kind of monitor could be used with Sun UltraSPARC 1 Creator Workstation other than the original Sun-provided monitor? Can a more modern monitor be used with this workstation?

Answer (score 5):

If memory serves - they use [13W3 connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DB13W3) - and you should be able to get a VGA to 13W3 adaptor. There's different varieties of them for different vendors, and a 'universal' one with dip switches that can be set to work.

I'm unsure how they'd work with a 'modern' widescreen and you'd likely be running the monitor on a non native resolution, but its the one option you have.

Comment: Seconding the non-native resolution. Sun used some slightly odd ones on the Creator cards: 1152 x 900 or 1280 x 1024 at 76/66 Hz, or 960 x 680 at 112 Hz

Comment: @scruss 1152 x 900 was generally used by Sun.  If I recall correctly originally chosen to be able to fit in 1 MB RAM for a monochrome bitmap.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yup, I know. I got these numbers and their slightly weird sync values from the Sun Ultra 1 Creatror service manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19127-01/ultra1.ws/802-4148-11/802-4148-11.pdf

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sun cgsix color graphics fb needed 1 MB (1152x900@8bit depth) but a bwtwo gets by with 128 kB (?) so 1MB for a 8 bit depth X pseudocolor (ie 256 different colors at the same time)